# How to give ASP.NET access to a private key in a certificate in the certificate store?

Tags: asp.net, certificate, iis-7.5, winhttp

I have an ASP.NET application that accesses private key in a certificate in the certificates store. On Windows Server 2003 I was able to use winhttpcertcfg.exe to give private key access to the NETWORK SERVICE account. How do I give permissions to access a Private Key in a certificate in the certificate store (Local Computer\Personal) on a Windows Server 2008 R2 in an IIS 7.5 website?

I've tried giving Full Trust access to "Everyone", "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool", "IIS_IUSRS", and everyother security account I could find using the Certificates MMC (Server 2008 R2). However the below code demonstrates that the code does not have access to the Private Key of a certificate that was imported with the private key. The code instead throws and error everytime the private key property is accessed.

**Default.aspx**
`<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Cert
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Public Key
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Private Key
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <%#((X509Certificate2)Container.DataItem).GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false) %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <%#((X509Certificate2)Container.DataItem).HasPublicKeyAccess() %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <%#((X509Certificate2)Container.DataItem).HasPrivateKeyAccess() %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table></FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>`

**Default.aspx.cs**

`using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Web.UI;
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
    public X509Certificate2Collection Certificates;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Local Computer\Personal
        var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        // create and open store for read-only access
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        Certificates = store.Certificates;
        repeater1.DataSource = Certificates;
        repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string HasPublicKeyAccess(this X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        try
        {
            AsymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = cert.PublicKey.Key;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "No";
        }
        return "Yes";
    }
    public static string HasPrivateKeyAccess(this X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        try
        {
            string algorithm = cert.PrivateKey.KeyExchangeAlgorithm;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "No";
        }
        return "Yes";
    }
}`

Answer (score 226, accepted):

1. Create / Purchase certificate. Make sure it has a private key.
2. Import the certificate into the "Local Computer" account. Best to use Certificates MMC. **Make sure to check "Allow private key to be exported"**
3. Based upon which, IIS 7.5 Application Pool's identity use one of the following.

   - IIS 7.5 Website is running under ApplicationPoolIdentity. Open MMC => Add Certificates (Local computer) snap-in => Certificates (Local Computer) => Personal => Certificates => Right click the certificate of interest => All tasks => Manage private key => Add `IIS AppPool\AppPoolName` and grant it `Full control`. Replace "*AppPoolName*" with the name of your application pool (sometimes `IIS_IUSRS`)
   - IIS 7.5 Website is running under NETWORK SERVICE. Using Certificates MMC, added "NETWORK SERVICE" to Full Trust on certificate in "Local Computer\Personal".
   - IIS 7.5 Website is running under "MyIISUser" local computer user account. Using Certificates MMC, added "MyIISUser" (a new local computer user account) to Full Trust on certificate in "Local Computer\Personal".

Update based upon @Phil Hale comment:

Beware, if you're on a domain, your domain will be selected by default in the 'from location box'. Make sure to change that to "Local Computer". Change the location to "Local Computer" to view the app pool identities.

Comment: For me, errors, only OK if user logged in server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774382/iis-6-private-key-certificate-access/2817702#2817702

Comment: How to configure ("XXX" to Full Trust on certificate in "Local Computer\Personal") in Windows Server 2008 R2 ? run/mmc/file/add snap-in/certificates and ??? Thanks

Comment: When you have MMC Certificates opened to Local Computer\Personal, click on the "certificate" to view the certificates. (note: the following assumes the certificate is imported already, if not then import the certificate first) Right click on the certificate you want to grant Full control on. In the context menu, click "All Tasks", then in the submenu click on "Manage Private Keys". From there you can add whatever users you'd like to have 'read' access to the private key for the certificate.

Comment: Make sure the local computer is selected in the "from the location" box. This stumped me for a while. The domain was selected by default so it didn't find the app pool identity user until I changed the location to the local computer

Comment: Since you're adding full trust to Certificates/Personal this surely means that you must import the same certificate in the personal store and not just Certificates/Trusted Root... I have to access certificates from `StoreName.Root` buy you can't set permissions on those. You can only set permissions on Personal certificates as much as I'm aware...

Comment: @RobertKoritnik After you've given the correct permissions you can move it out of /Personal and into the proper store. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580326/privatekey-trust-permissions-for-local-machine-trusted-roots-certificates/10594123#10594123 
( Update: I see that is your question. Sorry I didn't see the comment earlier. )

Comment: On AWS's Windows 2012 R2 EC2 VM's (IIS 8 based) you need to give `IIS_IUSRS` access to the certificate private key

Comment: "Make sure to check "Allow private key to be exported" is one part of the voodoo that make the context-menu “All Tasks”, “Manage Private Keys”.

Comment: observe the space between 'IIS' & 'AppPool'   IIS AppPool

Answer (score 48):

Note on granting permissions via MMC, Certs, Select Cert, right-click, all-tasks, "Manage Private Keys"

Manage Private Keys is only on the menu list for Personal... So if you've put your cert in Trusted People, etc. you're out of luck.

We found a way around this which worked for us. Drag and drop the cert to Personal, do the Manage Private Keys thing to grant permissions. Remember to set to use object-type built-ins and use the local machine not domain. We granted rights to the DefaultAppPool user and left it at that.

Once you're done, drag and drop the cert back where ever you originally had it. Presto.

Comment: yes this works well. I mentioned it in an answer on the following post however another answer was accepted even though the accepted answer is much longer and requires downloading a WCF file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580326/privatekey-trust-permissions-for-local-machine-trusted-roots-certificates/10594123#10594123

Comment: any solution for win2003 server?  it doesn't have the Manage Private Keys as an option like windows 7

Comment: @sonjz - check out [this technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662329.aspx), it mentions using the command line `winhttpcertcfg`

Comment: If you need private keys for certificates for anything but personnal, you most likely are doing something wrong... All other locations are for other/external entities that you trust. You should not have their private keys. Their public keys (certificates) should be enough. I would even dare to say that if you have their private keys, you should not trust them.

Answer (score 36):

If you are trying to load a cert from a .pfx file in IIS the solution may be as simple as enabling this option for the `Application Pool`.

Right click on the App Pool and select `Advanced Settings`.

Then enable `Load User Profile`

[image]

Comment: Why does this make a difference?

Comment: It must just be the way that windows is wired up. That it is maybe temporarily loading the profile into a user profile so it needs this option. I agree it’s odd that this is necessary when loading from a file that IIS has access to.

Answer (score 10):

I figured out how to do this in Powershell that someone asked about:

```
$keyname=(((gci cert:\LocalMachine\my | ? {$_.thumbprint -like $thumbprint}).PrivateKey).CspKeyContainerInfo).UniqueKeyContainerName
$keypath = $env:ProgramData + “\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\”
$fullpath=$keypath+$keyname

$Acl = Get-Acl $fullpath
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("IIS AppPool\$iisAppPoolName", "Read", "Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl $fullpath $Acl
```

Answer (score 7):

For me, it was nothing more than re-importing the certificate with "Allow private key to be exported" checked.

I guess it is necessary, but it does make me nervous as it is a third party app accessing this certificate.

Comment: thank you I did it this way X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certBytes, password,
                        X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

Answer (score 1):

Although I have attended the above, I have come to this point after many attempts.
1- If you want access to the certificate from the store, you can do this as an example
2- It is much easier and cleaner to produce the certificate and use it via a path

Asp.net Core 2.2
OR1:

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Operators;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Prng;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Math;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tursys.Pool.Storage.Api.Utility
{
    class CertificateManager
    {
        public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string caller)
        {
            AsymmetricKeyParameter caPrivateKey = null;
            X509Certificate2 clientCert;
            X509Certificate2 serverCert;

            clientCert = GetCertificateIfExist("CN=127.0.0.1", StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            serverCert = GetCertificateIfExist("CN=MyROOTCA", StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            if (clientCert == null || serverCert == null)
            {
                var caCert = GenerateCACertificate("CN=MyROOTCA", ref caPrivateKey);
                addCertToStore(caCert, StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

                clientCert = GenerateSelfSignedCertificate("CN=127.0.0.1", "CN=MyROOTCA", caPrivateKey);
                var p12 = clientCert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx);

                addCertToStore(new X509Certificate2(p12, (string)null, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet), StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            }

            if (caller == "client")
                return clientCert;

            return serverCert;
        }

        public static X509Certificate2 GenerateSelfSignedCertificate(string subjectName, string issuerName, AsymmetricKeyParameter issuerPrivKey)
        {
            const int keyStrength = 2048;

            // Generating Random Numbers
            CryptoApiRandomGenerator randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);

            // The Certificate Generator
            X509V3CertificateGenerator certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

            // Serial Number
            BigInteger serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(Int64.MaxValue), random);
            certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);

            // Signature Algorithm
            //const string signatureAlgorithm = "SHA256WithRSA";
            //certificateGenerator.SetSignatureAlgorithm(signatureAlgorithm);

            // Issuer and Subject Name
            X509Name subjectDN = new X509Name(subjectName);
            X509Name issuerDN = new X509Name(issuerName);
            certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(issuerDN);
            certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(subjectDN);

            // Valid For
            DateTime notBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
            DateTime notAfter = notBefore.AddYears(2);

            certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(notBefore);
            certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(notAfter);

            // Subject Public Key
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair subjectKeyPair;
            var keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, keyStrength);
            var keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
            keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
            subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

            certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

            // Generating the Certificate
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair issuerKeyPair = subjectKeyPair;

            ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA512WITHRSA", issuerKeyPair.Private, random);
            // selfsign certificate
            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);


            // correcponding private key
            PrivateKeyInfo info = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(subjectKeyPair.Private);


            // merge into X509Certificate2
            X509Certificate2 x509 = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(certificate.GetEncoded());

            Asn1Sequence seq = (Asn1Sequence)Asn1Object.FromByteArray(info.PrivateKeyAlgorithm.GetDerEncoded());
            if (seq.Count != 9)
            {
                //throw new PemException("malformed sequence in RSA private key");
            }

            RsaPrivateKeyStructure rsa = RsaPrivateKeyStructure.GetInstance(info.ParsePrivateKey());
            RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters rsaparams = new RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters(
                rsa.Modulus, rsa.PublicExponent, rsa.PrivateExponent, rsa.Prime1, rsa.Prime2, rsa.Exponent1, rsa.Exponent2, rsa.Coefficient);

            try
            {
                var rsap = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(rsaparams);
                x509 = x509.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsap);

                //x509.PrivateKey = ToDotNetKey(rsaparams);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ;
            }
            //x509.PrivateKey = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(rsaparams);
            return x509;

        }

        public static AsymmetricAlgorithm ToDotNetKey(RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters privateKey)
        {
            var cspParams = new CspParameters
            {
                KeyContainerName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                KeyNumber = (int)KeyNumber.Exchange,
                Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore
            };

            var rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
            var parameters = new RSAParameters
            {
                Modulus = privateKey.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                P = privateKey.P.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                Q = privateKey.Q.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                DP = privateKey.DP.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                DQ = privateKey.DQ.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                InverseQ = privateKey.QInv.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                D = privateKey.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                Exponent = privateKey.PublicExponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned()
            };

            rsaProvider.ImportParameters(parameters);
            return rsaProvider;
        }

        public static X509Certificate2 GenerateCACertificate(string subjectName, ref AsymmetricKeyParameter CaPrivateKey)
        {
            const int keyStrength = 2048;

            // Generating Random Numbers
            CryptoApiRandomGenerator randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);

            // The Certificate Generator
            X509V3CertificateGenerator certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

            // Serial Number
            BigInteger serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(Int64.MaxValue), random);
            certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);

            // Signature Algorithm
            //const string signatureAlgorithm = "SHA256WithRSA";
            //certificateGenerator.SetSignatureAlgorithm(signatureAlgorithm);

            // Issuer and Subject Name
            X509Name subjectDN = new X509Name(subjectName);
            X509Name issuerDN = subjectDN;
            certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(issuerDN);
            certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(subjectDN);

            // Valid For
            DateTime notBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
            DateTime notAfter = notBefore.AddYears(2);

            certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(notBefore);
            certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(notAfter);

            // Subject Public Key
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair subjectKeyPair;
            KeyGenerationParameters keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, keyStrength);
            RsaKeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
            keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
            subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

            certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

            // Generating the Certificate
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair issuerKeyPair = subjectKeyPair;

            // selfsign certificate
            //Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(issuerKeyPair.Private, random);

            ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA512WITHRSA", issuerKeyPair.Private, random);
            // selfsign certificate
            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);


            X509Certificate2 x509 = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(certificate.GetEncoded());

            CaPrivateKey = issuerKeyPair.Private;

            return x509;
            //return issuerKeyPair.Private;

        }

        public static bool addCertToStore(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 cert, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName st, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation sl)
        {
            bool bRet = false;

            try
            {
                X509Store store = new X509Store(st, sl);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                store.Add(cert);

                store.Close();
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            return bRet;
        }

        protected internal static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateIfExist(string subjectName, StoreName store, StoreLocation location)
        {
            using (var certStore = new X509Store(store, location))
            {
                certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                                           X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, subjectName, false);
                X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
                if (certCollection.Count > 0)
                {
                    certificate = certCollection[0];
                }
                return certificate;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

OR 2:

```
    services.AddDataProtection()
//.PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp-keys"))
.ProtectKeysWithCertificate(
        new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "clientCert.pfx"), "Password")
        )
.UnprotectKeysWithAnyCertificate(
        new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "clientCert.pfx"), "Password")
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

In Certificates Panel, right click some certificate -> All tasks -> Manage private key -> Add IIS_IUSRS User with full control

In my case, I didnt't need to install my certificate with "Allow private key to be exported" option checked, like said in other answers.