# Auto-deploy certificates to Windows certificate store in AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployments?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have an ASP.NET MVC5 application that requires two certificates:

1. An X509 elliptic curve certificate and it's corresponding private key (*.PFX)
2. An X509 elliptic curve certificate (*.CER)

to be available in the Windows Server 2012 R2's Certificate Store ("Local Machine" account, "Personal" store). To clarify, these certificates are used by the MVC5 app's code and **have *nothing* to do with SSL/TLS/HTTPS**.

Question: **How can I configure AWS Elastic Beanstalk, so that after deploying the MVC5 app, it already has those certificates and private keys in the certificate store?** AWS has configured the EC2 Windows Servers auto-provisioned via Elastic Beanstalk such that the ASP.NET apps run in IIS under the `IIS_IUSR` user permission, so we also would need to give `IIS_IUSR` permission to access the certificate private key. I'm not clear if IIS_IUSR is actually follows the principle of least-privilege or if I'm granting the wrong account the permission - but it does work (see below). We are currently deploying via AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2013 but are open to other deployment techniques if that helps the main problem.

---

Currently, we have an ugly, manual workaround which is

- remote into each instance, and in each instance do the following
- upload the certificate files (*cer and *pfx)
- manually run a batch file to load them into the cert stores (also have to add them to the Root store since they are self-signed certificates). The batch file looks like

> ```
> certutil -f -addstore Root OurCert-SS.cer // just a CER version of the PFX below 
> certutil -f -addstore Root RemoteCert-SS.cer 
> certutil -f -p test -importPFX MY OurCert-SS.pfx 
> certutil -f -addstore MY RemoteCert-SS.cer
> ```

- Manually Open MMC => Certificates (Local Machine) => Give `IIS_IUSRS` the `Full control` permission for the certificate's private key (otherwise the ASP.NET app can't get the private key).  Details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609859/how-to-give-asp-net-access-to-a-private-key-in-a-certificate-in-the-certificate/2647003#2647003)

Obviously this vastly kills the abstraction PaaS is supposed to provide because anytime instances scale or get recycled, we have to do the above :( ... so would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get this resolved?

Could you do something like what is described here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=591375, ignoring the web binding pieces and adding the permissions for the `IIS_IUSR`.

I thought I'd update with what we ended up doing.

We set up an ebextension to load the cert from s3 and then assign the required permissions.  I realize we did not have the .cer file to deal with so this may not work for you.

```
---
files:  
  "c:\\init_scripts\\install_cert.ps1":  
   content: |  
    $env = $args[0]   
    $pwd = $args[1]
    $securePwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -Force -asplaintext
    $certName="$($env).auth.cert.pfx"
    $certFilePath = "C:\$($certName)"
    Read-S3Object -BucketName ourcertsbucket -Key $certName -File $certFilePath
    $cert = Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certFilePath cert:\localmachine\my -Password $securePwd
    # Now that we have the cert we need to grant access to the IIS user for the cert
    Try
    {
      $WorkingCert = Get-ChildItem CERT:\LocalMachine\My |where {$_.Subject -match $env} | sort $_.NotAfter -Descending | select -first 1 -erroraction STOP
      $TPrint = $WorkingCert.Thumbprint
      $rsaFile = $WorkingCert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName
    }
    Catch
    {
      "        Error: unable to locate certificate for $($env)"
      Exit
    }
    $keyPath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\"
    $fullPath=$keyPath+$rsaFile
    $acl=Get-Acl -Path $fullPath
    $permission="IIS_IUSRS","Read","Allow"
    $accessRule=new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
    $acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
    Try 
    {
     Set-Acl $fullPath $acl
      "        Success: ACL set on certificate"
    }
    Catch
    {
      "        Error: unable to set ACL on certificate"
        Exit
    }
container_commands:  
  01_install_cert:  
   command: powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File .\\install_cert.ps1 %Environment% %CertPassword% 
   cwd: c:\\init_scripts  
   waitAfterCompletion: 0
```

Thanks to this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/1557e379-26a8-46d0-bf26-d32176395085/how-to-grant-permission-to-private-key-from-powershell) for the power shell permissions script