# Certificate private key throws CryptographicException under IIS Web Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-express

In my ASP.NET application I'm loading a certificate from the certificate store:

```
var myCert = CertificateUtils.GetCertificate("thumbprint");
```

This certificate contains a key pair which is used to decrypt the encrypted application settings.

The certificate is installed in *Personal* certificate store under the *Local Computer*. It works well when the application is running under the *IIS Express*. But if I execute it under the **full** *IIS Web Server*, the `myCert` instance is **missing the private key**.

The `PrivateKey` field of `myCert` object contains an exception:

```
'myCert.PrivateKey' threw an exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException'
```

I have checked that other fields of `myCert` object contain same values (like, for example, certificate serial number, thumbprint or expiration), so it seems it's getting the same certificate under both *IIS* and *IIS Express*. Only the private key is missing in the case of full *IIS*.

The only thing I have changed was the *Local Development Server* in project's properties ("Use IIE Express" / "Use IIS Web Server"). It's running inside the **Azure Emulator Express** in both cases.

Does anyone have an idea, why is this happenning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running on IIS Express, the program uses your credentials to access the certificate, while on IIS the pool identity's credentials are used. You can easily check the certificate ACL to see who is allowed or not.

Follow these steps:

1. **Check what Application Pool your web site uses**

   Open *Internet Information Services Manager*, select *Sites* in the *Connections* tree on the left. Select your site in the middle panel and click *Basic settings* under *Actions* on the right panel.
2. **Check what identity the Application Pool uses**

   Select *Application Pools* in the *Connections* tree on the left and find the identity in the middle panel. It'll be probably "NETWORK SERVICE".
3. **Add read permissions for the identity used by Application Pool to your certificate**

   Open the *Microsoft Management Console* (`mmc`), add the *Certificates* snap-in for local Computer account and find your certificate under *Personal* certificates. Open its context menu, *All Tasks* and *Manage Private Keys...*. Click *Add..*, enter the identity ("NETWORK SERVICE") and click *Check Names* and *OK*. Under *Permissions for*  allow only the *Read* permission.

   You can read details in this question: [How to give ASP.NET access to a private key in a certificate in the certificate store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609859/how-to-give-asp-net-access-to-a-private-key-in-a-certificate-in-the-certificate)

Comment: I see. That does make a sense. But what can I do to use that certificate and keys under the full IIS, please?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy you can grant the pool identity access to the certificate. It is very easy to do so in mmc's certificate management snap in.

Comment: OK, so I identified the Application Pool used for my application. Identity of this Application Pool is set to "NetworkService", so I need to grant an access to the certificate for this account, right? I have checked the Certificates in MMC, but I wasn't able to find where permissions are configured. Could you help me, please? Also what permission do I need?

Comment: I have solved it already, this StackOverflow question helped me with a certificate permissions set up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609859/how-to-give-asp-net-access-to-a-private-key-in-a-certificate-in-the-certificate.

Comment: How to overcome this exception without any IIS settings?

Comment: @Sonali you cannot. There is no magic. You must follow the answer to make relevant settings.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this problem to debug the application ".PrivateKey' threw an exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException"
I solve like this:

In mmc > Local Computer > Personal > Certificate > right click on certificate > All Tasks > Manage Private Keys:
Add "everyone" user and select Total Control.

Comment: This solution doesn't work in my scenario..I have already set highest permission for almost IUSRS,Everyone,IUSR...but still the same exception of "store.storehandle threw an exception of type system.security.cryptography.cryptographicexception" is fired..Any advice..highly appreciated.

Comment: This worked for me. Only had to add "Everyone" with only Read permission.