# How to give IIS (6.1) in Windows 7 access to certificate in LocalMachine (storeLocation) and My (storeName)?

Tags: iis, certificate, private-key, application-pool

I have installed a cert. In Manage Private Keys I have added everything. Even then a web app hosted in IIS can't request successfully. The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel error. This is only in Windows 7. Adding IIS_USRS in private key access works fine in Windows Server 2008. Any leads please?

I have seen almost everything about this and still can't figure it out.

Update: It is x.509 .p12 file.

Comment: What kind of certificate?

Comment: It is x.509 .p12 file.

Comment: Maybe I am not clear enough above. But after seeing almost everything about this, I assume you fully understand what is a certificate, and its various attributes, such as its usage (server authentication or client authentication), and so on, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509 You might update your question to include such, or it cannot be answered at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609859/how-to-give-asp-net-access-to-a-private-key-in-a-certificate-in-the-certificate) for thames' answer. He is a legend. Certs are more complex than they should be